# check null or undefined value for array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, node-async

I have an array in the following format and i have to check whether there is any null or undefined value

```
[{
         "categoryName": "A",
         "product": [{
          "catogoryName": "A",
          "price": "10",
          "productName": "a"
         }, {
          "catogoryName": "A",
          "price": "100",
          "productName": "a2"
         }, {
          "catogoryName": "A",
          "price": "5654",
          "productName": "dfhdh"
         }, {
          "catogoryName": "A",
          "price": "572",
          "productName": "d"
         }]
        }, {
         "categoryName": "B",
         "product": [{
          "catogoryName": "B",
          "price": "10",
          "productName": "b"
         }, {
          "catogoryName": "B",
          "price": "300",
          "productName": "b2"
         }]
        }]
```

I have tried with the following code, but it always gives me `success:1` message.

```
 var validateCategoryList = function (categoryList,callback) {
        async.eachSeries(categoryList, function (categoryChunk, callback) {
            var categoryName = categoryChunk.categoryName;
            var productList = categoryChunk.product;
            console.log(categoryName);
            if(!(categoryName == null || categoryName == undefined)){
                async.eachSeries(productList, function (item, callback) {
                    var productName = item.productName;
                    var price = item.price;
                    console.log(productName);
                    console.log(price);
                    if((!(productName == null || price == undefined)) || (!(productName == null || price == undefined))){
                        callback(null);
                    }
                    else{
                        callback({'success':'0','result':{},'errorMessage':'CategoryLIst invalid'})
                        return;
                    }
                },function (err) {
                    callback(null);
                });
            }
            else{
                callback({'success':'0','result':{},'errorMessage':'CategoryLIst invalid'})
                return;
            }
        },function (err) {
            callback({'success':'1'})
        });

    }
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: if there is an null value I have to get a response which shows that it holds a null value, otherwise the rest of process will continue.

Comment: where do you need the null value check?

Comment: This is a bulk input from front end , I have to check whether any of the value is null or undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `callback` to `JSON.stringify` as a poor-man's way to traverse the object:

```
function hasNull(obj) {
  let result = false;

  JSON.stringify(obj, (_, v) => v === null || v === undefined ? result = true : v);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Works fine in versions of node which support arrow functions.